# What is an epoch in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

What is an epoch in TensorFlow and what is it used for?

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L173

Answer (score 45):

An epoch, in Machine Learning, is the entire processing by the learning algorithm of the entire train-set.

The MNIST train set is composed by 55000 samples.
Once the algorithm processed all those 55000 samples an epoch is passed.

Answer (score 17):

An epoch is a full iteration over samples. The number of epochs is how many times the algorithm is going to run. The number of epochs affects directly (or not) the result of the training step (with just a few epochs you can reach only a local minimum, but with more epochs, you can reach a global minimum or at least a better local minimum).
Eventually, an excessive number of epochs might overfit a model and finding an effective number of epochs is crucial. This can be done by early stopping after measuring a given metric on a validation set (it should not be done with the test set).

Answer (score 4):

Epoch is an approach by which we pass the same dataset multiple times to the network in order to find optimal weights.

As we are using Gradient descent for optimization and there is a possibility of landing at local minima, so in order to overcome that we pass the same dataset n times (i.e. n Epochs) to find optimal weights.

Here, the number of Epochs is subjected to application and a smaller number of Epochs might lead to underfitting while a larger number of iteration could end up introducing overfitting.

Answer (score 3):

Epoch is not something intrinsic to the TensorFlow framework. It has been used for a long time in the field of Machine Learning.

One epoch is the time step that is incremented every time it has went through all the samples in the training set.

Answer (score 2):

An epoch is one training iteration, so in one iteration all samples are iterated once. When calling tensorflows train-function and define the value for the parameter epochs, you determine how many times your model should be trained on your sample data (usually at least some hundred times).

Answer (score 2):

epoch: how many times the algorithm goes over the training data.

FYI:
low epoch -- > underfit
high epoch --> overfit

optimal epoch: only known through experimentation. So just set the epoch high and use callbacks to stop training when the (average) validation error is higher than the (average) training error.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit more to other answers. Consider it as number of chances given to algorithms to improve its prediction.

Consider the following sequential code which will try to get double of value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TensorFlow.js get double of a number</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Get double of number</h2>
    <input type="text" id="txtBoxNumber" />
    <br />
    Nearly : <input type="text" id="txtBoxDouble" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const model = tf.sequential();
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [1] }));

        // Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer.
        model.compile({ loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd' });

        // Generate some synthetic data for training. (y = 2x)
        const xs = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9,10,11,12], [12, 1]);
        const ys = tf.tensor2d([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16,18,20,22,24], [12, 1]);

        // Train the model using the data.
        model.fit(xs, ys, { epochs: 99999 });

        $(document).on('keyup', '#txtBoxNumber', function () {
            setInterval(getDouble, 1000);
        });
        function getDouble() {
            $('#txtBoxDouble').val(model.predict(tf.tensor2d([parseInt($('#txtBoxNumber').val())], [1, 1])).dataSync()[0]);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have removed await to model.fit() method this will predict the output while other epoch are still in progress.

Comment: This wont show any effect on JSFiddle. Insted use it in local machine. Add some high value to test it.